# Creating ionic list with thumbnails, buttons and clickable rows

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to create an ion-list where each row has the following items from left to right

A thumbnail with an image from a URL OR and an ionic with 'clipboard'
A small text string
A tappable button/icon with the iso-information-circle-outline image (will be used to show a popover
A right-arrow at the far side showing that tapping this row will take them user to the next page

Originally I had the ngFor loop producing buttons for each row, and that made the arrow at the end appear, but stopped any buttons inside each row for being tapped correctly.

Other variants have meant the buttons are not aligned with text or if I use an ion-label around {{survey.label}} the button disappears altogether.

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let survey of surveys" (click)="openSurvey(survey)">
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
            <img *ngIf="survey.icon" width="35" src="{{survey.icon}}"/>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!survey.icon" name="clipboard"></ion-icon>
        </ion-thumbnail>
        {{survey.label}}
        <button (click)="showSurveyInfo($event, survey);$event.stopPropagation();" ion-button icon-only clear >
            <ion-icon name="ios-information-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-button item-end icon-only clear>
            <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-item>
```

[image]

This is how I'd like to lay it out, all there red parts are just annotations for this question. The Title and I have their vertical enters horizontally aligned. There is a subtitle in the lower half of the row and the lower text stops, preferably with an ellipsis (though probably out of scope for this question) so that the right arrow is always visible. Note too that the circle around the I is complete. In my current mark it is within a button and that clips the top and bottom off the icon.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a mockup of what exactly you want? Like show what good state looks like?

Comment: I've added a mockup of the intended outcome.

Comment: Hey Craig, good mockup a few more questions: 1. is blue (i) icon a button as well? 2. Do you need text truncating or you want opposite?

Comment: 1) I used an ion-icon inside a button to make the I appear, it needs to be clickable to open something different than tapping on the rest of the row. 2) I want the image on left and arrow on the right to be where they are no matter how much text tries to be in the middle. If the subtitle is too long then ideally it would be truncated with "...", otherwise just being cutoff is fine. Basically it't can't go outside of the bounds you see above.Thanks.